# Was bedeutet diese Mineralbeschreibung?

Tags: translation, technical-terminology, handwriting

Was sagt diese Beschreibung? Es ist eine Beschreibung eines Minerals, im Jahre 1856 geschrieben. Ich kann sagen, dass es sich um Chlorsilber handelt; aber ich habe Probleme beim Lesen, was da steht.

[image: Chlorsilber]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Interessanterweise werden hier zwei Handschriften vermischt: Namen, Fachbegriffe, fremdsprachige Teile sind wie im Fraktursatz mit einer international besser verständlichen Schrift geschrieben.

> *48.*
>   Chlorsilber,
>   zum Theil rein und derb, zu Theil
>   mit Quarz gemengt; als dicke
>   Platte zwischen Quarz liegend.
>   Chili.
>   (von *Juan Stuven* aus Valparai-
>   so. *1856*.)

- *Theil* ist die alte Schreibung von *Teil*.
- Offenbar ist *rein und derb* (veraltete) Fachsprache.
- Heute würde man vermutlich eher *vermengt* als *gemengt* sagen, aber vielleicht in der Fachsprache auch nicht.
- *Chili* kennt man inzwischen als *Chile*, dafür heißt der „Chilepfeffer“ jetzt so.
- Die letzten beiden Buchstaben der Ortsbezeichnung [*Valparaiso*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valpara%C3%ADso) stehen auf einer neuen Zeile. Damals sah der Trennungsstrich eher aus wie ein Gleichheitszeichen.

Die blaue Ergänzung:

> Jedenfalls, wie
>   No 47, Hg-haltig
>   siehe die dortige Notiz!

- *No* steht für Nummer.
- *Hg* ist das chemische Symbol für Quecksilber.

Comment: Ich habe mir erlaubt. Durch einen Edit die 2. Zeile im bauen einzufügen. Ich hoffe das ist ok für Dich.

Comment: @BerndGit: community wikis sind dafür gedacht.

Comment: Was hat es denn nun mit „derb“ auf sich oder verlese ich mich da?

Comment: @Crissov: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27652310#27652310

Comment: @Crissov: Ich halte den wie ein Komma aussehenden Punkt nach 47 tatsächlich für ein Komma und _wie No 47_ für einen durch Kommata abgegrenzten Einschub. Auch bei _48._ denke ich nicht, daß es als Ordinalzahl zu lesen ist, sondern der Punkt dient der Verdeutlichung der Orientierung (hier nicht zwingend nötig, aber z.B. bei 68 gegenüber 89).

Comment: @Crissov: Habe es jetzt zurückgeändert.

Comment: Rechts unten steht ja noch *12,-* . Ist das ein Preis?

Comment: Als Chemiker würde ich nicht *gemengt* sondern *vermengt* sagen. Allerdings bin ich Organiker; kein Mineralologe oder dergl.

Comment: @Jan Auch Fachsprachen verändern sich und der Text ist immerhin 160 Jahre alt.

Comment: @Crissov Stimme zu. Obiger Kommentar sollte die Bestätigung sein, dass *gemengt* heutzutage nicht mehr verwendet wird (und keine Aussage über die Vergangenheit treffen). War müde, ich hätte es besser formulieren können ^^'